# Error in generic twitter bootstrap sticky-footer-with-navbar example?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, navbar

I'm trying to create a sticky footer in bootstrap, and am using the default template provided here: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/sticky-footer-navbar.html

It appears the example provided has a problem; when the page is viewed through a smaller resolution, the navbar collapses (as it should), but then the 60px padding that originally kept the content from hiding under the navbar creates a large gap between the navbar and the content.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way to change this behaviour is to remove the 60px padding when the navbar collapses. Something like this should do the trick:

```
@media (max-width: 979px) {

#wrap > .container {
padding-top: 0;
}

}
```

You might have to change the div names to match your naming.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

it should maybe be

```
#push, #footer {
min-height: 60px;
}
```

instead of just height

Comment: sorry i totally misread the question .. I got distracted when i saw the footer was not flush to the base of the browser

Comment: that padding should not be based on the main content . there should be a floating div about the navbar to fix the size between the two pieces of content. <div id="fix-top-space"></div><div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">

Comment: " floating div about" *about = above ><